# How to get a user's posts into my fan page tab?

Tags: php, facebook-wall

I am basically looking to create an app in php for my CEO who wants a tab in the company facebook page where all the postings he makes in his wall appear real time in this page tab too. And the fans can comment to his wall posts on the same page.  He doesnt want to be the admin.

I must also have a feature in the same tab such that the user can also subscribe to his posts.

I am a beginner looking for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help

http://www.kimwoodbridge.com/how-to-add-the-facebook-fan-page-widget-to-your-website/